# Adjoint of a linear map w.r.t. nondegenerate pairing

Tags: linear-algebra

I am facing problem in a very basic question in linear algebra. **I am trying to do basis-free arguments.**

Let $\dim_F V<\infty$. Let $\langle ,\rangle:V^*\times V\rightarrow F$ be a non-degenerate bilinear mappping (i.e. $\langle \phi,v\rangle=0$ for all $v$ implies $\phi=0$ and $\langle \phi,v\rangle=0$ for all $\phi$ implies $v=0$.)

Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear map.

**To show:** There is at least one linear map $T^*:V^*\rightarrow V^*$ such that
$$\langle T^*\phi, v\rangle = \langle \phi,Tv\rangle \hskip1cm (\forall v\in V, \forall \phi\in V^*).$$

---

I am not getting where should I start?

I am not moving for uniqueness now; but I got stuck in proving existence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's consider an operator on $V^*$, defined by
$$\Omega : \psi \in V^* \mapsto \langle \psi, \cdot \rangle \in V^*.$$
Note, due to bilinearity, this map is a linear operator. We also have $\psi \in \ker \Omega \implies \langle \psi, \cdot \rangle = 0$, i.e. $\langle \psi, v \rangle = 0$ for all $v \in V$. Non-degeneracy implies $\psi = 0$, so $\Omega$ is injective. Since it is an operator on a finite-dimensional space, it is also surjective.

Now, if $T : V \to V$ is a linear operator, then for each $\phi \in V^*$, the map $v \in V \mapsto \langle \phi, Tv \rangle$ is a scalar-valued linear map, and hence belongs to $V^*$. Applying $\Omega^{-1}$ to this linear map yields a linear map $\psi$ such that
$$\forall v \in V, \langle \psi, v \rangle = \langle \phi, Tv\rangle.$$
For a fixed operator $T$ and pairing, this $\psi$ depends only on $\phi$. We can call it $T^*\phi$.

We have a couple of things left to do: we first need to show that this vector $T^*\phi$ is unique, then we need to show $T^*$ is a linear map. I know you're not yet trying for uniqueness yet, but it's important to show, otherwise $T^* \phi$ may not even be a well-defined map, let alone a linear one!

Suppose $\psi_1, \psi_2 \in V^*$ such that
$$\forall v \in V, \langle \psi_1, v \rangle = \langle \phi, Tv\rangle = \langle \psi_2, v \rangle.$$
Then, $\langle \psi_1 - \psi_2, v \rangle = 0$ for all $v \in V$. By non-degeneracy, this implies $\psi_1 = \psi_2$, so we do indeed get a unique value for $T^* \phi$.

Now, suppose $\phi_1, \phi_2 \in V^*$. Let $\psi_i = T^*\phi_i$ for $i = 1, 2$. Also, let $\psi = T^*(\phi_1 + \phi_2)$. Then, for all $v \in V$,
\begin{align*}
\langle \psi_1, v \rangle &= \langle\phi_1, Tv \rangle \\
\langle \psi_2, v \rangle &= \langle\phi_2, Tv \rangle \\
\langle \psi, v \rangle &= \langle\phi_1 + \phi_2, Tv \rangle.
\end{align*}
Adding the first two equations and subtracting the third, we get,
$$\langle \psi_1, v \rangle + \langle \psi_2, v \rangle - \langle \psi, v \rangle = \langle\phi_1, Tv \rangle + \langle\phi_2, Tv \rangle - \langle\phi_1 + \phi_2, Tv \rangle = 0.$$
Thus,
$$\forall v \in V, \langle \psi_1 + \psi_2 - \psi, v \rangle = 0.$$
Non-degeneracy implies $\psi_1 + \psi_2 = \psi$, i.e. $T^*(\phi_1 + \phi_2) = T^*\phi_1 + T^*\phi_2$, hence $T^*$ is additive. Scalar homogeneity can be proven similarly.

Comment: The use of notation $V^*$ in this answer is confusing because in the original question it's not clear this is assumed to be the space $L(V)$ of linear functionals on $V$. Presumably you didn't mean $\Omega$ to be the identity map but the natural isomorphism between these two. :)

Comment: @blargoner Yes, that's right. I assumed $V^*$ to be the dual of $V$. I would interpret normally "$L(V)$" as the space of operators on $V$, but I think we're on the same page. It's true, it isn't made especially clear that $V^*$ is the dual of $V$, but the argument works assuming that $V^*$ is any space over $F$ of the same dimension as $V$ (and I believe the result is false otherwise).